# Beautiful soup parsing XML

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, flickr

I have this datastructure.

```
<photo id="123" owner="12345" secret="xx" server="12" farm="4" title="109L_0195" 
ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" views="0" tags="military czechrepublic kmk koně 
humpolec všestrannost humpoec vysocinaregion" latitude="49.550933" longitude="15.36652" 
accuracy="16" context="0" place_id="tg5cqdpWW7q18rE" woeid="790349" geo_is_family="0" 
geo_is_friend="0" geo_is_contact="0" geo_is_public="1">
 <description>
Kvalifikační kolo KMK - všestrannost 18.7.2014 - Humpolec
</description>
</photo>


<photo id="123" owner="06" secret="xx" server="12" farm="4"   
title="Ytterligare en bild ifrån inspelningen av Johan Stjerquist's video: Nudist 
Javisst." ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" views="0" tags="square squareformat 
iphoneography instagramapp uploaded:by=instagram" latitude="56.171184" 
longitude="14.741144" accuracy="16" context="0" place_id="u4MzsN9ZW7KnPWo" 
woeid="898740" geo_is_family="0" geo_is_friend="0" geo_is_contact="0" geo_is_public="1">
<description/>
</photo>
```

Its a peace of information about a photo accessed through the Flickr API.
I want to extract the following information:
    id
    title
    tags
    longitude
    latitude

which I tried to accomplish through this.

```
url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=5....b&per_page=250&accuracy=1&has_geo=1&extras=geo,tags,views,description"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))

for data in soup.find_all('photo'):
    print (data.attrs['id' , 'title' , 'tags' , 'latitude' , 'longitude' , 'accuracy'])
```

That did not work. The `attrs` accepts only one argument. Looking at the documentation of `BeautifulSoup` it looks like there is no other tool which could help me getting all the information or am I mistaken (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)? I tried to substitute `attrs`through `p` but that did not work neither.

Any ideas which command I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`attrs`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) is a dictionary, you can get only specific keys using dictionary comprehension:

```
keys = {'id', 'title', 'tags', 'latitude', 'longitude'}
for photo in soup.find_all('photo'):
    print({key:value for key, value in photo.attrs.iteritems() if key in keys})
```

Note that you should use `items()` in case of Python-3.x.

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit messed up. Can edit it anymore. Here the edited version.
I am very new to python, so forgive me if I am about to ask something stupid. The values returned, are they stored in a dictionary as well, right? If I would feed my first `loop` a `list` with a lot of links to be iterated through (so the `url`would be a list with different URLS behind it), would it append the returned `values` to the `dic`or overwrite it since every link will be called seperately

Comment: @Christoph well, this code just demonstrates how you can grab specific attributes for every photo and print it out. You can collect them into list if you want - depends on what is your desired goal is.

Comment: thats what I want to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876399/smartest-way-to-store-huge-amounts-of-data/24876613?noredirect=1#comment38639634_24876613