# Smartest way to store huge amounts of data

Tags: python, database, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, bigdata

I want to access the flickr API with a REST request and download the Metadata of approx. 1 Mio photos (maybe more).
I want to store them in a .csv file and import them then into a MySQL Database for further processing

I am wondering what is the smartest way to handle such big data. What I am not sure about is how to store them after accessing the website in Python, passing them to the .csv file and from there to the db. Thats one big questionmark.

Whats happening now (for my understanding, see code below) is that a `dictionary` is created for every `photo` (250 per called URL). This way I would end up with as many dictionaries as photos (1 Mio or more). Is that possible? 
All these `dictionaries` will be appended to a list. Can I append that many dictionaries to a list? The only reason I want to append the dictionaries to the list is because it seems way easier to save from a list, row per row, to a .csv file.

What you should know is that I am a complete beginner to programming, python or what so ever. My profession is a completely different one and I just started to learn. If you need any further explanations please let me know!

```
#accessing website
list = []
url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=5...1b&per_page=250&accuracy=1&has_geo=1&extras=geo,tags,views,description"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url)) #soup it up
for data in soup.find_all('photo'):
    dict = {
        "id": data.get('id'),
        "title": data.get('title'),
        "tags": data.get('tags'),
        "latitude": data.get('latitude'),
        "longitude": data.get('longitude'),
    }
print (dict)

list.append(dict)
```

I am working with python 3.3. The reason why I do not pass the data direct into the db is because I cannot get the python connecter for mysql db on my os x 10.6 to run.

Any help is very appreciated.
Thank you folks!

Comment: The usage of a .csv middleman is inefficient, time-consuming, and tricky. Why isn't your MySQL Python driver working? I'd argue that that's the problem you should solve first (if possible), and is a completely different question.

Comment: I tried to solve and wanted to burn my computer afterwards and jump out of the window. But here I am, try to work around.

Comment: ask that question on this site - you're going to want that MySQL driver at some point, right?

Comment: I am not sure. It caused me so much trouble. If I can do it SQLite or something else I rather do it with that.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using SQLite for prototyping this rather than messing with CSV. SQLite works very well with python but you don't have to go through all the headache of setting up a separate database.

Also, I don't think you want to use BeautifulSoup for this, since it doesn't sound like scraping is what you really want. It sounds like you want to access the REST API directly. For that you'll want to use something like
[the requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/#)
or better yet
[one of the flickr Python bindings](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/).

Once you have that up and running, I would write to the DB during each iteration of the loop, saving as you go. That way you're not using tons of memory and if something crashes you don't lose the data you've pulled so far.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the hint to flickr python bindings. Did not know about them! I thought its webscraping cause I call a website which is formatted in XML and I try to extract information out of it?
I`ll have a look at SQLite

Comment: I've never used the flickr API but it looks like you can use several different formats. I recommend JSON. So your resquest format would be REST and your response format JSON.

Comment: Then I wont be able to parse it with bs. Whats better about JSON compared to XML?

Comment: Correct you shouldn't need BeautifulSoup at all. JSON is less verbose than XML, so less text required to store the same amount of information. There are good and bad things about this, but when it comes down to it JSON is easier to read as a human. Also, many (most?) new APIs use JSON exclusively.

Comment: I'll have a look at it. The XML output from the Flickr API is very easy to read. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875004/beautiful-soup-parsing-xml/24875160?noredirect=1#comment38643165_24875160 for an example.

Comment: Well yes after you parse it with BeautifulSoup it will be easy. I mean in the raw format if you look at an XML file vs the same data in JSON most people prefer JSON. See [here](http://json.org/example)

Comment: In that example JSON to be more understandable to the human eye. But the Flickr API gives out nice formatting (see link I gave you). I might stick to beautifulsoup and the XML parsing